# Weird behaviour of MySQL while selecting greatest in group

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Suppose I have a table `surveys` like this:

> customer | last_survey_result | date (int)

```
CREATE TABLE `surveys` (
`id`  int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`customer`  int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`survey_result`  tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1' ,
`date`  smallint(2) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `optimize` USING BTREE (`customer`, `survey_result`, `date`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
;
```

Every customer can make several reviews. If he does not complete it, `last_survey_result=-1`.

I want to know what is the last rating of every customer, as well as it is not `-1`. If he has never answered any, the result is the default `-1`.

For example if we have this

```
customer | survey_result | date (int)  
    a    |    -1         |     1
    a    |     7         |     2
    b    |    -1         |     1
    b    |    -1         |     2
    c    |    10         |     1
    c    |     8         |     2
    d    |    -1         |     1
    d    |     7         |     2
```

The result has to be:

```
customer | last_survey_result
    a    |       7
    b    |      -1
    c    |       8
    d    |       7
```

Here is what I tried. In fact it works for this data:

```
SELECT a.customer, a.survey_result last_survey_result
  FROM surveys a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN surveys b
  ON a.customer=b.customer AND (a.date < b.date AND b.survey_result>=0)
  WHERE b.customer IS NULL 
GROUP BY customer;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd4c5/3)

**The problem is** in the example I am getting the results well, but in my database, this will happen:

```
customer | survey_result | date (int)  
    a    |    -1         |     1
    a    |     5         |     2
    a    |    -1         |     3
    b    |    -1         |     1
    b    |     8         |     2
    b    |    -1         |     3

customer | last_survey_result
    a    |       -1
    b    |        8
```

I think it is weird and do not have a clue what can be happening. Can it be something related to indexes? I am completely lost.

Comment: This is due to MySQL's sloppy implementation of the GROUP BY operator. Your statement is illegal in all other DBMS. See here for details: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Comment: Ufff, I thought `GROUP BY` would do a good job here. So what would be the best way to solve it, @a_horse_with_no_name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying your code to separate the two case (at least one non-negative result - all negative results):

```
SELECT a.customer, a.survey_result AS last_survey_result
  FROM surveys a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN surveys b
  ON a.customer = b.customer AND (a.date < b.date AND b.survey_result >= 0)
  WHERE a.survey_result >= 0 
    AND b.customer IS NULL 

UNION ALL

SELECT customer, -1
  FROM surveys
  GROUP BY customer
  HAVING MAX(survey_result) < 0 ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd4c5/44)**

---

And here are two more ways to do it, without `UNION`. A triple `JOIN`:

```
-- solution 2 --
SELECT s.customer, 
       COALESCE(a.survey_result, -1) AS last_survey_result
  FROM 
      ( SELECT DISTINCT customer
        FROM surveys
      ) AS s
    LEFT JOIN
        surveys AS a
      JOIN 
        ( SELECT customer, MAX(date) AS date
          FROM surveys 
          WHERE survey_result >= 0 
          GROUP BY customer
        ) AS b
      ON  a.customer = b.customer 
      AND a.date = b.date 
    ON  s.customer = a.customer ;
```

and a `JOIN` with a correlated subquery at the `ON` clause:

```
-- solution 3 --
SELECT s.customer, 
       COALESCE(a.survey_result, -1) AS last_survey_result
  FROM 
      ( SELECT DISTINCT customer
        FROM surveys
      ) AS s
    LEFT JOIN
      surveys AS a
    ON  a.customer = s.customer 
    AND a.date =
        ( SELECT MAX(m.date)
          FROM surveys AS m
          WHERE m.customer = s.customer 
            AND m.survey_result >= 0 
        ) ;
```

Comment: I like it! In fact, it is funny because I was doing the same when I got your answer. It confirmed me I was on the good way : )

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be tougher than it looked, at least for me...

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.customer, COALESCE((
  SELECT     b.survey_result
  FROM surveys b
  WHERE a.customer=b.customer AND b.survey_result <> -1
  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1), -1) as last_result
FROM surveys a
```

[Here's an example via SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55769/2)

```
CREATE TABLE surveys
    (`customer` varchar(1), `survey_result` int, `date` int)
;

INSERT INTO surveys
    (`customer`, `survey_result`, `date`)
VALUES
    ('a', -1, 1),
    ('a', 5, 2),
    ('a', -1, 3),
    ('b', -1, 1),
    ('b', 8, 2),
    ('b', -1, 3),
    ('c', -1, 1),
    ('c', -1, 2),
    ('c', -1, 3),
    ('d', 9, 1),
    ('d', 6, 2),
    ('d', 4, 3)
;
```

Result

```
CUSTOMER    LAST_RESULT
a           5
b           8
c           -1
d           4
```

Comment: Mmmm, @a_horse_with_no_name was commenting that `GROUP BY` is not used properly the way we are doing.

Comment: You can make it correct by replacing b.survey_result with max(b.survey_result)

Comment: Well, no, because I do not need the MAX but the last one that was not -1.

Comment: Ok try that version without group by at all.  Click on the SQL Fiddle link to see it in action.

Comment: Hey, thanks @Dan Metheus, the pity is I get an error while trying to use it in SQL Fiddle.

Comment: @Dan Metheus - 
Try your code with three **positive values** for a given customer.

Answer (score 1):

The `GROUP BY` only makes sense when an aggregate function is present in the `SELECT` or `HAVING` clause.

Most RDBMSs will error when you specify a `GROUP BY` without an aggregate function, but MySQL is different.  In MySQL, the clause functions, but it is is *[non-deterministic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm)* when no aggregate function exists.  Typically it returns the first value in the table that it finds, but since this is not documented behavior in either the SQL standard or the MySQL documentation this isn't guaranteed, making it highly dangerous to assume that is the case.

This will do what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  a.customer,
  COALESCE(b.survey_result, -1) "last_survey_result"
FROM surveys as a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT customer,
      survey_result,
      date
    FROM surveys
    WHERE survey_result <> -1
    GROUP BY customer
    HAVING date = max(date)) as b
  ON a.customer = b.customer
```

Note that your SQL Fiddle returned unexpected results because you transposed the `date` and `survey_results` fields for customer 'a'.

Note also that this will not function in most other RDBMSs because the subquery is selecting `customer` and `survey_result` but only includes one of those two fields in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Were I not pressed for time I would rewrite it to be a more proper query likely by adding a third self-join.

Comment: Thanks! But I guess something must be incorrect, as I get c -> -1, while should be 8.

Comment: Wow, the subquery totally isn't behaving like I'm expecting it to.  It's completely deleting customer 'c', but I don't see why.  I'll try to fix it when I get back if nobody else has.

Comment: When I run this version I get -1 if there are 3 positive survey results for a customer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind getting the result back as a character field, the following will fetch the most recent result:

```
SELECT s.customer,
       substring_index(group_concat(s.survey_result order by date desc), ',', 1) last_survey_result
  FROM surveys s
where s.survey_result >= 0
GROUP BY customer;
```

You can, of course, `cast` is back to a tinyint.

To get all customers, but only positive survey results, move the condition to a case:

```
SELECT s.customer,
       substring_index(group_concat((cast when s.survey_result >= 0 then s.survey_result end)
                                    order by date desc), ',', 1) last_survey_result
FROM surveys s
GROUP BY customer;
```

`group_concat()` ignores NULL values.

Comment: Thanks! It looks interesting, although I get `;[Err] 1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'substring_index'`

Comment: @fedorqui . . . Sorry, I left out the delimiter.

Comment: Good, now it works. However, customer b does not appear, as it is the one having always `survey_result=-1`.

Comment: It is pathetic, sure, but it was not me. Thanks for editing with general view!